# Confronting values between dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to confront the equality of values contained into a different dataframes having different column names.

```
label = {
    'aoo' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'boo' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'coo' : ['a', 'b', 'c']
    'label': ['label', 'label', 'label']
}

unlabel = {
    'unlabel1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'unlabel2' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'unlabel3': ['a', 'b', 'hhh']

}

label = pd.DataFrame(label)
unlabel = pd.DataFrame(unlabel)
```

Desired output is a dataframe that contains the column where their values is equal and the column label.
Where a single value is not equal `unlabel['unlabel3']` i don't want to keep the values in the output.

```
desired_output = {
    'unlabel1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'unlabel2' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'label' : ['label', 'label', 'label']
}
```

If the labels where numbers I could try `np.where` but I can't find similar helper for string.

Could you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` and specify the columns to merge with `left_on` and `right_on`

```py
out = unlabel.merge(label, left_on=['unlabel1', 'unlabel2', 'unlabel3'], right_on=['aoo', 'boo', 'coo'], how='left').drop(['unlabel3', 'aoo', 'boo', 'coo'], axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

  unlabel1 unlabel2  label
0        a        a  label
1        b        b  label
2        c        c    NaN
```